# Creating a vector of objects and the class contains four members and able to access and delete a whole object

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, vector

First of all i'm very weak at C++ OOP ... I've this class contains four members i want to make a vector of object and able to insert and delete whole object based on search e.g. insert

> **Surname='john' Firstname='david' birthdate='1960'** and when i want to delete the whole object just search for John in the vector so how to connect between vector index of John and rest of his data and erase it e.g. `Add.erase(Add.begin()+index) ;` after getting the index of john in the vector or in the object

```
class Employees{
    public:

        vector <Employees> Add;

        int maxx =500;
        string Surname;
        string Firstname;
        string birthdate;
};
```

> The function for Adding a new Employee

```
void AddEmployee(vector < Employees > & Add) {
    Employees ZZ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        //Surname= s;
        string d;
        //Firstname=d;
        cin >> d;
        string c;
        cin >> c;
        //birthdate= c ;
        Add.push_back(ZZ);
        // Add.push_back(ZZ.FirstName) ;
        //  Add.push_back(ZZ.birthdate) ;
    }
    cout << endl << Add[0].Surname << endl;
};
```

> And this delete function that when i enter John search in vector of objects and get his index then delete the wole object

```
void DeleteEmployee(Employees & ZZ) {

    cout << " delete employee";
    string delete1;
    cin >> delete1;

    auto it = std::find(Add.begin(), Add.end(), delete1);
    if (it == Add.end()) {
        cout << " name not in vector " << endl;
    } else {
        auto index = distance(Add.begin(), find(Add.begin(), Add.end(), delete1));
        Add.erase(Add.begin() + index);
        // here should delete the whole object including Surname,Firstname,datebirth ? 
        // i'm not sure if it's correct
    }

}

int main() {

    // here any thing to display the vector members but i don't know how to do it 

}
```

Comment: I already showed you in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118344/65863) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117849/) how to delete employees by name from a vector.  And why does `Employees` now have a vector of nested `Employees`? That is simply not the right design.

Comment: If you want to be able to find employees by name, I'd advise looking up `std::map`and/or `std::unordered_map`. They can make this task considerably simpler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the problem was e.g. if i insert John and want to display this as index 0 and should show the whole word it prints only "J" and i assume the solutions for this is using array of struct but i don't want to use struct at all i want to make instance vector of object that i could delete the whole object at once

Comment: @JerryCoffin that's similar to std::pair also but i don't want to use this i just need the primary way my request it's the same as using array of struct but in c++ it's like inserting Surname,Firstname,birthdate in sequence and delete them in sequence also

Comment: @JohnnDoe "*if i insert John and want to display this as index 0 and should show the whole word it prints only "J"*" - then you are not displaying it correctly. "*i assume the solutions for this is using array of struct*" - an array, vector, map, etc, where the struct contains all of the relevant details of one entity (a single employee). "*i don't want to use struct at all*" - why? You are not learning good OOP by avoiding it, you are just making your code more complicated, and much more error prone, as demonstrated by your earlier code...

Comment: @JohnnDoe ... "*i want to make instance vector of object that i could delete the whole object at once*" - which is EXACTLY what I showed you how to do in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118344/65863).

Comment: but i want to access vector of object and class members instantly e.g. Add[0].Surname and Add[0].Firstname etc...

Comment: @JohnnDoe Again, I showed you EXACTLY how to do that in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118344/65863), via the vector of `Employee` (singular, not plural) structs.  If you don't understand what I showed you earlier, fine.  But don't dismiss and avoid it, go learn from it instead.  You are just bringing up old mistakes again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau your previous code is great but i like to use kind of Vector of class or object (similar as array of struct)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225504/discussion-between-johnn-doe-and-remy-lebeau).